# How to pass the arguments while executing a script where variable name is not known?

Tags: script, command-line-arguments

I have a script, when i execute it ask couple of arguments one by one.

```
[home]$ ./script_name

User> *input here*
Password> *input here*
Authentication ID> *input here*
Success !!
Select the Account (Enter 1 to 3)> *input here*
```

Due to some reasons i can't read this script but can someone please help me how can i pass these argument User, Password, Authentication ID, Account number while executing the script ?

The purpose is to execute this using python.

Appreciate the help.

Comment: Please add to the question which shell you are using and which language the script is in.

Comment: What happens if you add them on the command-line in the order that is asked?

Comment: @harrymc If i am passing something like ./script_name abc 123. It is doing nothing and still asking me to pass the value when the script executes

Comment: So the script is not using positional parameters (`$1` etc). Try now for flags: run `./script_name -u username`.